# making an application similar in android like that of iphone

Tags: android

I have to make application in android.similar to the that made in the iphone,,
Here is the link http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/road-trip-bingo/id376434962?mt=8#
can anybody tell me how should i proceed.Should i start with the User designing part first??  Thanks in advance
Tushar Sahni

Comment: Start with reading http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html :)

Comment: Sted i have started with with splash screen.After then i have created 2 views .....Now what to do??

Comment: To know what to do first design or code look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893908/what-should-come-first-the-design-pattern-or-the-code and search in SO on this topic you will find many questions discussing on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read this stackoverflow question ['port iphone application to android'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633742/port-iphone-application-to-android)

In addition to [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) I would suggest give a try to opensource [XMLVM](http://xmlvm.org/)

Comment: ok,,rabh,,whats ur email id,,, i want t o chat with u,,,seeking ur help